# A sequence in $C([-1,1])$ and $C^1([-1,1])$ with star-weak convergence w.r.t. to one space, but not the other

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces

The functionals
$$
  \phi_n(x) = \int_{\frac{1}{n} \le |t| \le 1} \frac{x(t)}{t} \mathrm{d} t
$$
define a sequence of functionls in $C([-1,1])$ and $C^1([-1,1])$.

a) Show that $(\phi_n)$ converges *-weakly in $C^1([-1,1])'$.

b) Does $(\phi_n)$ converges *-weakly in $C([-1,1])'$?

For me the limit functional
$$
 \int_{0 \le |t| \le 1} \frac{x(t)}{t} \mathrm{d} t
$$
is not well defined so i have trouble evaluating the condition of convergence? Do you have any hints?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "For me the limit functional ... is not well defined"? Is $x \in C^1$ or $x \in C$? Does that make a difference? (It does.)

Comment: Ok, i don't see why it makes a difference, i think the problem lies in the factor $1/t$, which is not defined at $t = 0$?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\int_{1/n<t<1}\frac{x(t)-x(0)}tdt$?

Comment: no, in the exercise its written without $x(0)$.

Comment: Yes, i thought about that, then the integral gets $\int_{0 \le |t| \le 1} \frac{1}{t}$, which is not finite i think...

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: In fact it is like you stated, there is an absolute value $1/n < |t| < 1$, so the integral splits into two parts and you can add and substract $x(0)$.

Comment: I didn't noticed the absolute value, now it's clear. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, i added the absolute value in an edit a few minutes ago, it wasn't there from the beginning... didn't knew thats is so important

Comment: @Stefan: $\lim_{c\to 0} \int_c^1 \frac{x(t)-x(0)}{t} dt$ is finite for $x\in C^1$ but not in general for $x\in C^0$, think of Taylors theorem.

Answer (score 1):

We can write 
$$\phi_n(x)=\int_{1/n}^1\frac{x(t)-x(-t)}tdt.$$
When $x$ is in $C^1[-1,1]$, this converge to $\int_0^1\frac{x(t)-x(-t)}tdt$ (and this integral is convergent, as the problem at $0$ is solved by the derivative.

Taking a continuous function $f$ such that $f=1$ on $[n^{-1},1]$ and $-1$ on $[-1,-n^{-1}]$, we can see that $\lVert \phi_n\rVert_{(C[-1,1])'}=2\log n$ so we can't have weak$^*$ convergence in $(C[-1,1])'$.

Comment: could your f choosen such that it is differentiable too, and then contradicting your conclusion that $\phi_n$ is weak* convergent in $C^1([-1,1])$?

Comment: No, because $\lVert\phi_n\rVert_{(C^1[-1,1])'}$ is bounded independently on $n$.

Comment: but why your $f$ not, think I can choose a function from $C^1([-1,1])$ with your property that $f=1$ on $[n^{-1},1]$ and $-1$ on $[-1, -n^{-1}]$?

Answer (score 0):

@Davide Giraduo

Regarding your derivation, i came to another result:
\begin{align*}
 \int_{1/n \le |t| \le 1} \frac{x(t)}{t} \mathrm{d} t & = \int_{-1}^{-1/n} \frac{x(t)}{t} \mathrm{d} t +  \int_{1/n}^1 \frac{x(t)}{t} \mathrm{d} t \\ 
                                                                                 & =  - \int_{1}^{1/n} \frac{x(-t)}{t} \mathrm{d} t +  \int_{1/n}^1 \frac{x(t)}{t} \mathrm{d} t \\ 
   & =  \int_{1/n}^{1} \frac{x(-t)}{t} \mathrm{d} t +  \int_{1/n}^1 \frac{x(t)}{t} \mathrm{d} t \\
                      & = \int_{1/n}^{1} \frac{x(-t) + x(t)}{t} \, \mathrm{d} t
\end{align*}
Which has others sign's?

Comment: The first "-" in the second row is wrong [$t\to -t$ and $dt\to -dt$].

Comment: i am confused, the rule for linear substitution as it is written in my textbooks reads, for $c \ne 0$: $\int_a^b f(cx) \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{c} \int_{ca}^{cb} f(t) \mathrm{d}t$ for $t(x) := cx$. I guess the transformation factor is the $\frac{1}{c}$, which I have put before the integral?

Comment: Yes, equivalently, $\int_a^b f(y) dy = \frac{1}{c} \int_{ca}^{cb} f(\frac{t}{c}) dt$. Now apply this for $f(y)=\frac{x(y)}{y}$.